# Can I set-up an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in the Application class?

Tags: java, android

I have one preference which handles the notifications. I am implementing OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in the settings activity which enables/disables the Alarm service(Note: I know it's a bad practice to use alarms for notifications. I'll be switching to GCM shortly).

The application has a login system. Now, I want to disable the Alarm service once the user has logged out. I change the `"notif"` `boolean` in SharedPreferences to `false`

Here's the question:- Can I implement the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in the Application class kinda like this

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("notif",false)){
            AlarmService.setAlarm(getBaseContext());
        }else {
            AlarmService.cancelAlarm(getBaseContext());
        }
    }
}
```

Is this right?

Also, additional tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can. You should create your singleton class for Shared Preferences data store management.

Comment: Thank you for that quick response. Also, is this common practice?

Comment: No need to do in common practices, if in case there is any requirement like this then you should follow. For singleton class you can refer https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/sharedpreferences-storage-standard-localstorage-class/